# Add JPA EntityListener/Spring Data AuditingEntityListener Programmatically

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using JPA and parts of Spring (like transaction management, JPA repositories) but I don't use Spring for dependency injection, and instead treat the Spring parts as POJO objects.  So far I have it working great:  I have runtime generated JPA repository classes and transactions are managed by the Spring classes.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to get the JPA auditing listener to work.

For example, here is my `BaseEntity` that defines the `EntityListener` class and the audit fields:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners( { AuditingEntityListener.class } )
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable
{
  @CreatedDate
  @Field( index = Index.YES, store = Store.YES )
  @Column( name = "date_created" )
  @Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
  private Date dateCreated;

  @CreatedBy
  @Column( name = "created_by" )
  private Long createdBy;

  //other stuff
}
```

You can see that I specify the Spring `AuditEntityListener` class.  All the other entity classes in the app extend this `BaseEntity` class.

Then, I have a class that implements `AuditorAware`:

```
public class JpaAuditConfiguration implements AuditorAware<Long>
{

  @Override
  public Long getCurrentAuditor()
  {
    //pretend there's real logic here...
    return new Long(0);
  }
}
```

Now, since I'm not using Spring or Spring Data to boot itself, I need a way to register this `JpaAuditConfiguration` with the `AuditingEntityListener`.

**My question:**  How do I register the `JpaAuditConfiguration` with the `AuditEntityListener` programmatically?

If it helps, I'm using Spring classes like `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`(to programmatically create the `EntityManagerFactory`) and `PersistenceUnitPostProcessor` to do the rest of the JPA configuration programmatically.  I'm looking for the hook that allows me to do entity audit listener registration I mention above.

I'm not using any `orm.xml` or `persistence.xml` JPA configuration files.

How can I do that?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
class Config {

  @Bean
  public AuditorAware<Long> auditorProvider() {
    return new JpaAuditConfiguration ();
  }
}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.auditing

Comment: I'm not using Spring Boot or Spring for DI, so I don't think those annotations will make any difference.

Comment: then how are you loading the persistent context?